# Can't install: Tailwind CSS Custom Forms plugin

Tags: npm, tailwind-css

When I run the command to install the plugin:
`npm install @tailwindcss/custom-forms --save-dev`

I get the following warning:

```
npm WARN @tailwindcss/custom-forms@0.2.1 requires a peer of tailwindcss@^1.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

I couldn't find any usefull information about this on google

Comment: have you tried installing the package its telling you to install?

Comment: it doesn't what i need to install

Comment: `requires a peer of tailwindcss@^1.0 but none is installed` - seems pretty straight forward to me

Comment: yea but tailwind is installed

Comment: is it? post your package.json you could be using an incorrect version

Comment: ```"devDependencies": {
    "@tailwindcss/custom-forms": "^0.2.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.0",
    "postcss": "^8.3.11",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.2.19",
    "xxxxx": "^1.0.3"
  }```

Comment: move the tailwindcss above the tailwindcss/custom-forms. It is trying to install it before it has tailwindcss installed

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue while installing `npm install @tailwindcss/custom-forms --save-dev` .To solve this run command for yarn:

```
yarn add -W tailwindcss@latest postcss@latest autoprefixer@latest
```

and for npm run:

```
npm i -W tailwindcss@latest postcss@latest autoprefixer@latest
```

and Then try to install again @tailwindcss/forms or any other plugin of tailwindcss. It will work. happ to share and help

For more information please check [here](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-forms/issues/31).

And further if you're facing problem of  `Error: PostCSS plugin tailwindcss requires PostCSS 8.` Then run this command:

```
npm install tailwindcss@npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat postcss@^7 autoprefixer@^9
```